# Updating a List from another List based on Index (line number)

Tags: c#, winforms

I believe this is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529725/c-sharp-update-a-list-from-another-list), however, I need this based on equal indexes.

---

I have a list like this:

```
  Time   | Temp1 | Temp2 |  Type

10:42:00 |  108  |  150  | Unkwon 

10:44:00 |  107  |  160  | Test

10:46:00 |  108  |  130  | Test22
```

I have another like this:

```
ID | Type

40 | New1

80 |  New2

100 | Test22
```

I don't have a field to compare both lists. Because of this, I would like to use the index (line number) of the list and <> Type.

So,

Line 1 and 2 should update because they present different type.

---

Result expected:

```
  Time   |  Temp1  |  Temp2  |  Type

10:42:00 |   108   |   150   |  New1

10:44:00 |   107   |   160   |  New2

10:46:00 |   108   |   130   |  Test22
```

---

What do I have:

```
foreach (var x in Graph._listData)
{
     var itemToChange = newData2
         .First(d => 
             d[newData2.IndexOf(1)] == Graph._listData.IndexOf(1)).Type = x.Type;
}
```

I believe that the whole idea of this code is wrong but it what I got at this point.

The structure of my tables:

```
public struct GraphData
{
    public double Temp1;
    public double Temp2;
    public DateTime Date;
    public string Type;
}

public struct GraphDataWithID
{
    public int IdHeader;
    public string Type;
}
```

- So, how do I accomplish the comparison between two lists based on the index?

Comment: You can just use a `for` loop if this is a `List` or an array.  Or you can use `Enumerable.Zip`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use Linq:

```
var n = Graph._listData.Count;
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (Graph._listData[i].Type != newData2[i].Type) {
        var temp = Graph._listData[i]; 
        temp.Type = newData2[i].Type; 
        Graph._listData[i] = temp;
    }
```

I edited accordingly to what [juharr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302918/juharr) pointed out: if you have a list of immutable structs, you can't modify the struct elements in place.

Comment: Hey, if I try like this I get the error "Cannot modify the return value of 'List<FormA_DataType.GraphData>.this[int]' because it is not a variable" on the part "Graph._listData[i].Type = newData2[i].Type;"

Comment: @FabioSoares That means you have a list of structs.  So you'll have to get a copy of the struct out, change the value, then put the updated copy back into the collection.  However if your struct it mutable then you're going to have a lot of other problems.  Basically you need to do `var temp = Graph._listData[i]; temp.Type = newData2[i].Type; Graph._listData[i] = temp;` for it to work.

Comment: Just to note that if instead of list the `_listData` was array, the `struct` members could be modified in place as in the original answer.

Comment: It works!!! Thank you. I marked the other one as correct (because was answered first) but this one also works. Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually this one was answered first, but I would advice you to keep juharr answer as accepted because it is more complete and offers 2 different methods

Comment: My idea is to save what I found on "Graph._listData[i].Type" to "newData2[i].Type". Right now, if I enter the function with Type="something" in Graph._listData[i] I am leaving Type="" in Graph._listData[i]. This is happening in the part "temp.Type = newData2[i].Type;" because newData2 is empty. In other words,instead of having newData2 with information from "Graph._listData[i].Type" I am leving with both lists with the original value of newData2

Comment: Please create a new question, with precise explanation and properly formatted code

Comment: @Lovy, sounds like a plan! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Note: this works for reference types only.

An alternative to using a `for` loop is `Zip`

```
var zipped = Graph._listData.Zip(
    newData2, 
    (o,n) => new { Original = o, NewDate= n})
foreach(var pair in zipped)
{
    pair.Original.Type = pair.NewData.Type;
}
```

The nice thing about `Zip` is that it will stop with the shorter of the two collections, so if `newData2` has fewer rows you don't have to do any special checks to make sure the index is out of bounds.

However for a `List` of structs a `for` loop would be a better idea since you have to use a temp variable to hold the copy of the struct, update it, and assign it back to the original position in the `List`.

```
int end = Math.Min(Graph._listData.Count(), newData2.Count())
for(int i = 0; i < end; i++)
{
    if(Graph._listData[i].Type != newData2[i].Type)
    {
        var temp = Graph._listData[i];
        temp.Type = newData2[i].Type;
        Graph._listData[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I try to do like this, I get the error "Cannot modify the return value of 'List<FormA_DataType.GraphData>.this[int]' because it is not a variable" in the part "Graph._listData[i].Type = newData2[i].Type;"

Comment: @FabioSoares I'v updated the for loop to handle structs.

Comment: @FabioSoares Also I'd highly recommend you change `FormA_DataType` to a `class` if you can because [mutable structs are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil)

Comment: It works! I will double check changing FormA_DataType to a class, several people commented about this, thank you!

Comment: Hey, it is not working properly... Sorry about that. I should save what I found on "Graph._listData[i].Type" to "newData2[i].Type". Right now, if I enter the function with Type="blabla" in Graph._listData[i] I am leaving Type="" in Graph._listData[i].  This is happening in the part "temp.Type = newData2[i].Type;". I should replace the information from "newData2[i].Type" to  "Graph._listData[i].Type" and not the opposite. Can you help me?

Comment: And if I try to invert, from "Graph._listData[i] = temp;" to "newData2[i].Type" I get the same error then before - Cannot modify the return value of 'List<FormA_DataType.GraphDataWithID>.this[int]' because it is not a variable

Comment: And if I try the "Zip" method, I also get a similar error: 
Cannot modify the return value of '<anonymous type: FormA_DataType.GraphData Original, FormA_DataType.GraphDataWithID NewDate>.Original' because it is not a variable

Answer (score 1):

You can join the lists like this.  It uses the overload of the Select method that uses a Func with an index.

```
var joined = from left in leftList.Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
             join right in rightList.Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
               on left.i equals right.i
             select new { left.s.Time, left.s.Temp1, left.s.Temp2, right.s.Type };
```

Comment: Haha that's a nice solution but a bit overkill